# Try to create basic math game

Tags: javascript, html, math

I'm doing a math game. I have this HTML/JavaScript code. It generates a random number but when I  input the correct answer, it still displays 'wrong'. I'm not sure what went wrong.

Here is HTML code:

```
<table width="400" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="number1">1</div></td>
    <td><div>+</div></td>
    <td><div id="number2">2</div></td>
    <td><div>=</div></td>
    <td><input type="text"></input></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Check"></input></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
//random number appear when start game
var number1;
var number2;

number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML=number1;
document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML=number2;

//Answer
var answer = number1 + number2;

//add click handler with check answer
var checkAnswer = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
var value = checkAnswer.value;
var btn = document.querySelector('input[type=button][value=Check]');


btn.onclick = function() 
{
  if (value == answer) 
       {
          alert('You are correct');
       }
   else{
          alert('You are incorrect, the answer was ' + answer);
       }

 document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value = "";               
 document.getElementById('number1').innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById('number2').innerHTML = ""; 
 number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
 number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
 document.getElementById('number1').innerHTML = number1; 
 document.getElementById('number2').innerHTML = number2;

 answer = number1 + number2


};
```

Comment: its not java code  its javascript. Java and java script both are very different.

Comment: @KrishnaVerma java script or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare answer to value in `checkAnswer`:

```
if (checkAnswer.value == answer) { 
  //correct 
}else{
  //incorrect
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move following lines in `.onclick` method.

```
var checkAnswer = document.querySelector('input[type=text]'); //needn't be moved in method
var value = checkAnswer.value;
```

You can verify the result from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxvo3fay/).

The problem was the variable `value` is initialize with empty string when you load the page, as when page is loaded the value is empty.

Comment: `checkAnswer` is not initialized with empty string `value` is. Also only the value needs to be moved. The `querySelectory` is valid before and more efficient.

Comment: @Abhishek can you please explain document.querySelector('input[type=text]'); please

Comment: @varadmayee Sure. It gets the first input tag of type text in the HTML. In this case, it is the answer textbox. You can know more about it from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't update the `value`.

In the button click event update the value. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v7vthvx/1/).

```
btn.onclick = function() 
{
    value = checkAnswer.value;

    ...
```